# No strong duality In spite of Slater's condition

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I was reading some course notes [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/17-dual-corresp.pdf).

On Page 8, it says:

> Note that strong duality holds here (Slater's condition), but the
>   optimal value of the last problem is not necessarily the optimal
>   lasso objective value

How is this even possible?

---

What they are essentially doing for establishing duality is taking an unconstrained problem and making it constrained through the use of a dummy variable. Then, the dual is taken. I don't understand why the values of the primal and dual objectives will not be the same.

Comment: I've got to be honest, I'm not sure, either. You should contact the author directly if possible.

Comment: Isn't that just because they removed the $\|y\|_2^2$ (and of course the minus sign)?

Answer (score 1):

The equation entitled "lasso dual" at the top of slide 8 in https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/17-dual-corresp.pdf
DOES have the same value as the original lasso problem, by strong duality.

But then they transform to an "equivalent" problem, which will attain its optimum at the same point, but will have a different optimal value. In the equivalent version, they have dropped both the 1/2 scale factor and the norm of y term, and they have also flipped the sign of everything to transform from a maximization to a minimization problem... so of course it will have a different optimal value.

This whole slide is to illustrate the "Dual Subtleties" they describe on slide 6.